# Xamarin Forms Android OnAppearing Not Triggering After PopModalAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there a work around for Android not triggering after PopModalAsync is called while still using a Modal page. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinForms
{
    public class OnAppearingBug : ContentPage
    {
        Label label;
        public OnAppearingBug ()
        {
            label = new Label {
                Text = "Page"
            };
            Button button = new Button {
                Text = "PushModal"
            };
            button.Clicked += (sender, e) => Navigation.PushModalAsync (new PopModalBug ());

            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = { label, button }
            };
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing(){
            label.Text = "OnAppearing";
        }
    }
}

using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinForms
{
    public class PopModalBug : ContentPage
    {
        public PopModalBug ()
        {
            Button button = new Button {
                Text = "Pop Back"
            };
            //Bug: This will not trigger OnAppearing on Android
            button.Clicked += (sender, e) => Navigation.PopModalAsync();

            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = { button }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. The reason from docs of NavigationPage (somewhat similar to Modal Push & Pop) 
`For each Xamarin.Forms.Page that you push or pop, the Android implementation of Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage simply adds or removes the content of the page to or from a single activity.`

Answer (score 6):

see also http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21417/navigationpage-push-pop-event-sequence-different-across-platforms and http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18781/ios-and-android-different-behaviors-for-onappearing

but as of the moment (Xamarin.Forms 1.2.2) the only/best solution is the one propose by CrisWebb above:

on your main page - 
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "popped", (sender) =>
            {
                // code to run
            });

on your modal page - 
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "popped");

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue as indicated by keith_r.

As an alternative to MessagingCenter you can use Xamarin.Forms.Application events triggered when modal page are pushed or popped.

Application events described [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/#Modal_Navigation_Events).

In your Xamarin.Forms.Application MyApp class you can keep an handle of your OnAppearingBug Page. In MyApp you can listen for modal page pushing/poppig and commanding OnAppearingBug Page as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple work around. For example, my modal page is a Calendar where the user has to select a date before the POP.

So, inside the Modal Page class just create an Event (in my case OnDateSelected)
and create a reference from its parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to `await` when u call your `Async` methods, for example, the button click should be like this:

```
    button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => await Navigation.PopModalAsync();

    button.Clicked += async (sender, e) => await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PopModalBug ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Im actually having the same problem at the moment. Its pretty frustrating because there isn't even a way to roll your own with a custom renderer, as all forms pages are considered the one activity on android, and it therefore doesn't get any lifecycle notifications at all.

The only solution I have found is to use the [MessagingCenter](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/). All you need to do is send a message to your content page from your popup when it is disappearing. Its a bit of additional work and spaghetti, but at the moment it is really the only way.

Apparently there are some additional features coming soon which may help with this problem, but at the moment, there isn't much else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use pushModalAsync method to directly navigate to a page.